# RHEL: Nautilus terminal is installed but still doesn't show up in the context menu options to open sh files

Tags: terminal, rhel, nautilus

Nautilus terminal is installed but still doesn't show up in the context menu options to open sh files. I am trying to open an sh file but it does not give the option of opening with terminal from the context menu. How may I add open with terminal to context menu.

```
bash-4.2$ sudo yum install nautilus-open-terminal
[sudo] password for <user>: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ps, search-disabled-repos
Package nautilus-open-terminal-0.20-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is the installed programs, quite another is the personal configuration your environment uses. You'll have to find out how to add it there.

What desktop are you using?